# java.lang.IllegalStateException: A connection to a distributed system already exists in this VM. It has the following configuration:

Tags: java, illegalstateexception, geode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqiC9.png)    public class GemfireTest {

```
            public static void main(String[] args) throws NameResolutionException, TypeMismatchException, QueryInvocationTargetException, FunctionDomainException {


                ServerLauncher serverLauncher = new ServerLauncher.Builder()
                        .setMemberName("server1")
                        .setServerPort(40404)
                        .set("start-locator", "127.0.0.1[9090]")
            .build();
                serverLauncher.start();
                 String queryString = "SELECT * FROM /gemregion";
                ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory().create();
                QueryService queryService = cache.getQueryService();
                Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);
                SelectResults results = (SelectResults)query.execute();
                int size = results.size();
                System.out.println(size);
            }
        }
```

trying to run a locator and a server inside my java application getting an exception below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A
>   connection to a distributed system already exists in this VM.  It has
>   the following configuration:   ack-severe-alert-threshold="0"
>   ack-wait-threshold="15"   archive-disk-space-limit="0"
>   archive-file-size-limit="0"   async-distribution-timeout="0"
>   async-max-queue-size="8"   async-queue-timeout="60000"
>   bind-address=""   cache-xml-file="cache.xml"
>   cluster-configuration-dir=""   cluster-ssl-ciphers="any"
>   cluster-ssl-enabled="false"   cluster-ssl-keystore=""
>   cluster-ssl-keystore-password=""   cluster-ssl-keystore-type=""
>   cluster-ssl-protocols="any"
>   cluster-ssl-require-authentication="true"   cluster-ssl-truststore="" 
>   cluster-ssl-truststore-password=""   conflate-events="server"
>   conserve-sockets="true"   delta-propagation="true"
>   deploy-working-dir="C:\Users\Saranya\IdeaProjects\Gemfire"
>   disable-auto-reconnect="false"   disable-tcp="false"
>   distributed-system-id="-1"   distributed-transactions="false"
>   durable-client-id=""   durable-client-timeout="300"
>   enable-cluster-configuration="true"
>   enable-network-partition-detection="true"
>   enable-time-statistics="false"   enforce-unique-host="false"
>   gateway-ssl-ciphers="any"   gateway-ssl-enabled="false"
>   gateway-ssl-keystore=""   gateway-ssl-keystore-password=""
>   gateway-ssl-keystore-type=""   gateway-ssl-protocols="any"
>   gateway-ssl-require-authentication="true"   gateway-ssl-truststore="" 
>   gateway-ssl-truststore-password=""   groups=""
>   http-service-bind-address=""   http-service-port="7070"
>   http-service-ssl-ciphers="any"   http-service-ssl-enabled="false"
>   http-service-ssl-keystore=""   http-service-ssl-keystore-password=""
>   http-service-ssl-keystore-type=""   http-service-ssl-protocols="any"
>   http-service-ssl-require-authentication="false"
>   http-service-ssl-truststore=""
>   http-service-ssl-truststore-password=""   jmx-manager="false"
>   jmx-manager-access-file=""   jmx-manager-bind-address=""
>   jmx-manager-hostname-for-clients=""   jmx-manager-http-port="7070"
>   jmx-manager-password-file=""   jmx-manager-port="1099"
>   jmx-manager-ssl-ciphers="any"   jmx-manager-ssl-enabled="false"
>   jmx-manager-ssl-keystore=""   jmx-manager-ssl-keystore-password=""
>   jmx-manager-ssl-keystore-type=""   jmx-manager-ssl-protocols="any"
>   jmx-manager-ssl-require-authentication="true"
>   jmx-manager-ssl-truststore=""   jmx-manager-ssl-truststore-password=""
>   jmx-manager-start="false"   jmx-manager-update-rate="2000"
>   load-cluster-configuration-from-dir="false"   locator-wait-time="0"
>   locators="127.0.0.1[9090]" ***(wanted "")***   lock-memory="false"
>   log-disk-space-limit="0"
>   log-file="C:\Users\Saranya\IdeaProjects\Gemfire\server1.log"
>   ***(wanted "")***   log-file-size-limit="0"   log-level="config"   max-num-reconnect-tries="3"   max-wait-time-reconnect="60000"
>   mcast-address="/239.192.81.1"   mcast-flow-control="1048576, 0.25,
>   5000"   mcast-port="0"   mcast-recv-buffer-size="1048576"
>   mcast-send-buffer-size="65535"   mcast-ttl="32"
>   member-timeout="5000"   membership-port-range="[1024,65535]"
>   memcached-bind-address=""   memcached-port="0"
>   memcached-protocol="ASCII"   name="server1" ***(wanted "")***
>   off-heap-memory-size=""   redis-bind-address=""   redis-password=""
>   redis-port="0"   redundancy-zone=""   remote-locators=""
>   remove-unresponsive-client="false"   roles=""
>   security-client-accessor=""   security-client-accessor-pp=""
>   security-client-auth-init=""   security-client-authenticator=""
>   security-client-dhalgo=""   security-log-file=""
>   security-log-level="config"   security-manager=""
>   security-peer-auth-init=""   security-peer-authenticator=""
>   security-peer-verifymember-timeout="1000"   security-post-processor=""
>   security-shiro-init=""   security-udp-dhalgo=""
>   serializable-object-filter="!*"   server-bind-address=""
>
>   server-ssl-ciphers="any"   server-ssl-enabled="false"
>
>   server-ssl-keystore=""   server-ssl-keystore-password=""
>
>   server-ssl-keystore-type=""   server-ssl-protocols="any"
>
>   server-ssl-require-authentication="true"   server-ssl-truststore=""
>
>   server-ssl-truststore-password=""   socket-buffer-size="32768"
>
>   socket-lease-time="60000"   ssl-ciphers="any"   ssl-cluster-alias=""
>
>   ssl-default-alias=""   ssl-enabled-components="[]"
>
>   ssl-gateway-alias=""   ssl-jmx-alias=""   ssl-keystore=""
>
>   ssl-keystore-password=""   ssl-keystore-type=""   ssl-locator-alias=""
>   ssl-protocols="any"   ssl-require-authentication="true"
>
>   ssl-server-alias=""   ssl-truststore=""   ssl-truststore-password=""
>
>   ssl-truststore-type=""   ssl-web-alias=""
>
>   ssl-web-require-authentication="false"   start-dev-rest-api="false"
>
>   start-locator="127.0.0.1[9090]"* (wanted "")*
>   statistic-archive-file=""   statistic-sample-rate="1000"
>   statistic-sampling-enabled="true"   tcp-port="0"
>   udp-fragment-size="60000"   udp-recv-buffer-size="1048576"
>   udp-send-buffer-size="65535"   use-cluster-configuration="true"
>   user-command-packages=""   validate-serializable-objects="false"
>
> at
>   org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.validateSameProperties(InternalDistributedSystem.java:2959)
>     at
>   org.apache.geode.distributed.DistributedSystem.connect(DistributedSystem.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.geode.cache.client.ClientCacheFactory.basicCreate(ClientCacheFactory.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.geode.cache.client.ClientCacheFactory.create(ClientCacheFactory.java:214)
>     at GemfireTest.main(GemfireTest.java:61)

How to solve this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is pretty self explanatory: you can’t have more than one connection to a distributed system within a single JVM. In this particular case you’re starting both a server cache (`ServerLauncher`) and a client cache (`ClientCacheFactory`) within the same JVM, which is not supported.

To solve the issue, use two different applications or JVMs, one for the server and another one for the client executing the query.

Cheers.

Comment: Can we connect to the same gemfire cache server using different cache configuration(cache.xml)?

Comment: Hello Suresh, I'm not sure I understand your question... as long as there's only one connection per JVM, you can use whatever you want to connect to the distributed system (Java API, `cache.xml`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Juan for the reply.I want to load two different cache.xml to the same gemfireClient instance.I tried with getting the current instance of gemfireClient using ClientCacheFactory.getAnyInstance() method and then loading the second cache.xml using loadXml() method.The approach not worked.Can you suggest any possible approach of loading two cache.xml file into the clientCache instance?

Comment: Hello Suresh. You can't load two different `cache.xml` into one single cache instance... why don't use a single `cache.xml` file with the whole configuration instead?. Maybe I can suggest a workaround if you describe the use case with more detail.

Comment: ,I have one web-service which have its own code to connect the gemfire instance with its cache.xml file.I have developed an application which connects to the gemfire instance with its cache.xml.This application should be used as an external jar or library to the developed web-service.The problem is that , I can't able to do it as the web-service has already initiated the client cache instance with its own cache.xml and in the flow when the code of the external jar is invoked then the code failed.I want to achieve the above use case.Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: The problem in the end is the same as before: you are trying to create more than one cache instance per JVM, which is not allowed. If both the `web service` and the `application` connect to the same distributed system, you could try to invoke `ClientCacheFactory.getAnyInstance()` and use the method `createClientRegionFactory` to create the local regions manually instead of initialising the cache from scratch through the `create` method.

Comment: Thanks Juan.I tried the same approach and instead of using create method I have used loadCacheXml() method.But,this approach didn't work.Did you ever try to use loadCacheXml() method?